# How do I unversion my documents library?

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I was trying to import an Android project, and accidentally imported the project into my documents library (Win7, `Libraries/Documents`), instead of a folder *within* the Documents library (`C:\Users\myUser\Documents\AndroidJava`)

This has lead to some interesting issues with the Read-Only-ness of the Documents library. I would like to correct which folders are source controlled, but I am unable to determine how to do so (I tried searching for "SVN Unversion Documents", but that, understandably, failed to produce results)

How can I fix my Documents folder?

[image]

Comment: I would just delete all of the files and re-import into a sub folder like you wanted, or am I missing some bigger problem with your `My Documents` folder?

Comment: @burnttoast11 That does not remove the versioning from the documents library (i.e., all the non SVN files still have Tortoise's (?) for unversioned files)

Comment: Is there a hidden .svn folder? If there is deleting that folder might get rid of the (?)s.

Comment: There was, and it seems to work intermittently. There is currently no svn folders (hidden or otherwise), and while the items within the Documents library are no longer being marked unversioned by SVN, the folders still are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and re-installing TortoiseSVN seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tortoise Unversion-Option in kontext-menu of files or folders:

[image]

---

Icon explanation:

[image]

Overlay Handler ([picture source](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html)):

[image]

Exlude Path ([picture source](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html)):

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to be an option. I've updated the OP with a picture.

Comment: As I can see in your screenshot the folders are not under version control. The folder with red exclamation mark is under control. I add a screenshot of Tortoise-Settings to my answer where you can see Icon explanation.

Comment: The issue is, I don't want icons of *any* sort. I know those folders aren't versioned; I want Tortoise to stop telling me they aren't!

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: You can disable icon overlays -> see my answer I add a new screenshot.

Comment: I don't want to *remove* icon overlays **everywhere** (I'm using SVN elsewhere in the filesystem) -- what I want is for the icon overlays to only show for versioned folders. And the "versioned" folders in my Documents library, *aren't*.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Very hard to get you lucky ;-) but there is also for this a option: exclude paths -> see my answer and the new screenshot.

Comment: Was my answer no solution?